# How to measure car battery current precisely in wide range (starter current, charging)

Tags: current-measurement, high-current, shunt

I want to measure car battery currents in high resolution and in wide range and both directions (including engine start and charging currents).

I don't need very high precision measurement, but I want high resolution.

I decided to use large 600A/60mV 0.5% accurracy shunt.

I have lots of amazing Microchip MCP3424 4 channel ADCs in my workshop, it's my favourite ADC and I want to use it.

I figured out, that typical op-amp in differential mode is bad idea, it produces a lot of error (offset voltage error? noise?). It's too hard for me to get reasonable precision witch such low resistance shunt and general purpose op-amp.

There are auto-zero, low noise, low offset amplifiers, dedicated differential amplifiers, but my op-amp knowledge is not enough to make use of them, but I found that there is easier way - dedicated current monitor amplifiers.

My general idea looks like this (sorry for Paint drawing):

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Which op amp for current sensing can I use? Price limit 3-5USD.
2. How to use it? Can I power it from USB, and measure current in another circuit?

I've seen datasheets, I've seen this:

[Need help with circuit design for current measurement of car starter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78270/need-help-with-circuit-design-for-current-measurement-of-car-starter)

But I'm not sure how to connect op amp power, ground etc.

Edit:

1. I realized that I don't need high side current sensing.
2. I made this incomplete schematic. Can someone help to fill it up?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh8vsX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/amplifiers-linear/current-shunt-monitor-products.page

Comment: Is a current clamp unsuitable or too expensive?

Comment: @JohnU Current clamps are much less accurrate as far I know. Im trying to get 0.5% acurracy. Current clamp with such precision will be waaay to expensive (if there are clamps with such precision). My goal is to build very affordable 60-240sps high current, high precision meter.

Comment: Accuracy, precision, resolution... what exactly are your actual criteria for this thing? You said "_I don't need very high precision measurement, but I want high resolution_" ...?

Comment: Your schematic looks okay so far. Check my updated answer for a great pdf resource on instrumentation amps.

Comment: @JohnU I want to get absolute acurracy about 0.5% in whole range (-20/+60mV). Resolution 12bit allows to measure with 0.02% steps. I want to make use of this, even when measurements will have little offset or gain errors i want to read ADC with 4096 steps. We will see what happends... Maybe thats too much.

Comment: Considering the age of this post I don't expect a reply, but what was the end result of all this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Believe it or not, I'm working on the exact same project as you.  I just installed my Deltec shunt today.  You should have a look at [this question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103417/determining-correct-requirements-of-instrumentation-amp-in-measuring-large-curre)

In a nutshell, I think (and have heard) that an instrumentation amplifier would be better for this for many reasons.  They have less error, better input impedance, CMRR

I will probably be going with an AD620 for the amp, and an MCP3301 for the ADC.  Anyways, there is a nice list of instrumentation amplifiers in the question I linked.

As for using an instrumentation amp, yes you can find some that are single supply which would let you power it from USB.

For instance, the [INA122](http://www.ti.com/product/ina122) is a single supply amp that can be powered by anything from 2.2 to 36V.  My only question would be: why? Are you going to route a wire from a cigarette to usb through the dash? You're creating a circuit to measure a car battery, why not use the car battery to power it? At least that's what I'm doing.

Here is my shunt inside a nice little box after hookup:

[image]

EDIT: I also just noticed you plan on placing the shunt on the high side.  While I'm sure this  would be fine for a decent instrumentation amp, it also seems unnecessary.  Why add in additional common mode voltage when you don't need to? Hence why mine is on the low-side.

One of the best resources I have come across is Analog's *[Designer's Guide to Instrumentation Amplifiers](http://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/dh-designers-guide-to-instrumentation-amps.html)*

The amount of detail, graphs, charts, and ease of explanation is incredible.  There are many useful things in this guide.

While it doesn't seem to specifically touch on low-side current sensing, I have read in several places that there are really only 2 disadvantages to low-side compared to high-side. Those are:

1. Inability to detect a short
2. Additional shunt resistance causes disturbance in ground path

The first one I don't see being much of a problem in a car, especially given that you've got a fuse box.

The second point I also do not see affecting a car too much, especially if your shunt is an extremely low value.  Your starter certainly has a resistance much higher than your shunt so it shouldn't really affect its performance.  Mine started just fine after hooking it up.

Comment: Actually... I just realized what "high side measurement amplifier" is. I don't need measurement on high side.

Comment: So, if I put it on low side - I need some kind of differential measurement anyway, because after engine starts - charging current will start flowing into battery.

Comment: Yep. No matter what you will need a differential amplifier to measure a differential voltage across a shunt. That's the playing field of instrumentation amplifiers.

Comment: Thats nice catch with detecting shorts and ground path disturbance. I think it's about mains powered devices, where you need low impedance ground path for fast circuit breaker turn off in case of short (more current - faster turn off, resistor in path - less current). I fully understand that. And that book looks amazing, it's gonna be hard/expensive to get it in my country :(

Comment: Can you share your schematics? I just want to see how you deal with negative voltage and how you power up amplifier.

Comment: Wait a second, is this really full book under that link?

Comment: @Kamil It's really common for the big IC manufacturers to release books/articles/app notes. Analog Devices released that book to the public so that you'll think about buying their parts the next time you need an instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: You can learn a lot from app notes.